# Adding attribute to child elements

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, elementtree

I am trying to add an attribute to all child elements in all XML files in the current directory. This attribute should be equal to the length of each string. For example, the XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8?>
    <RootElement>
        <String Id="PythonLove">I love Python.</String>
    </RootElement>
```

So, if this worked the way it should, it would leave the child opening tag looking like this:

`<String Id="PythonLove" length="14">`

I have read many forums and all point to either .set or .attrib to add attributes into an existing XML. Neither of these have any effect on the files though. My script currently looks like this:

```
for child in root:
    length_limit = len(child.text)
    child.set('length', length_limit)
```

I've also tried `child.attrib['length'] = length_limit`. This also doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the value to string before set.

```
>>> xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
... <RootElement>
...     <String Id="PythonLove">I love Python.</String>
... </RootElement>
... '''
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> root = ET.fromstring(xml)
>>> for child in root:
...     child.set('length', str(len(child.text)))  # <---
... 
>>> print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
<RootElement>
    <String Id="PythonLove" length="14">I love Python.</String>
</RootElement>
```

Comment: thank you falsetru. ok, so that is very close now. It prints to the command prompt correctly with the 'length' attribute. However, it is still not adding the attribute to the XML itself.

Comment: @coolhand2020, Do you mean `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`? Then see this: http://pastebin.com/s78aYw06 and let me know whether it is what you want. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Got it! Pretty elated because that was a couple weeks of struggles. I ended up just writing to 'infile' (used for iterating through the files in the cwd) and it worked to overwrite the existing XML (had to register the namespace first which was another little hump I ran into). Full code:

```
import fileinput
import os, glob
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

path = os.getcwd()

for infile in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml')): 
    try:
        tree = ET.parse(infile)
        root = tree.getroot() # sets variable 'root' to the root element

        for child in root:
            string_length = str(len(child.text)) 
            child.set('length', length_limit)

    ET.register_namespace('',"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/XML")   
    tree.write(infile)
```